# Почему Thread.sleep выдает InterruptedException (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

Добрый вечер!
Есть код, должен меняться текст после паузы, но выдается исключение, почему? Как правильно написать?

```
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources)
{
    loginfield.setStyle("-fx-font: 25 calibri");
    btn.setOnAction(
            event ->
            {
                if (loginfield.getText().equals(login))
                {
                    result.setText("Your login is right");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    result.setText("Logged in");
                }

                else if (loginfield.getText().isEmpty())
                {
                    result.setText("You have typed nothing");
                }

                else if (loginfield.getText() != login)
                {
                    result.setText("Your login isn't right");
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо кэлбек выполняется в ui потоке, а вы его пытаетесь приостановить, что не очень хорошо.

попробуйте через `java.util.Timer` выполнить смену текста:

```
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(() -> result.setText("Logged in"));
        }
    }, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
```